# css linking in html content throws get error on loading html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with jQuery's `.html()` method. I load a html content into a div by using this:

```
$('#content').html(domContent);
```

where `domContent` is containing a entire HTML string. It has a stylesheet linked to it. So while this line executes am getting `GET file:///....` error in the console, because the URL path of CSS file is not valid.

However later I modify the URL and get it to apply it on my page.

But I don't want this error to occur in the first place. It should ignore it or if any way I can tell jQuery to skip this GET error.

Comment: I don't think the `.html()` method fits your purpose here. Maybe the `.load()` method?

Comment: Why not fix the URL to the CSS file *before* you set the `html()`?

Comment: Did the answer below help at all, Khaleel?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(document.createDocumentFragment());` in this instance. As it suggests, it creates a document fragment, but doesn't add it into the page, so won't try to fetch the CSS from the broken URL. For example:

```
var $fragment = $(document.createDocumentFragment());
$fragment.html(domContent);

// Fix the CSS URL using the code you've already got, then:

$('#content').html($fragment.html());
```

If your unsure how the 'fix CSS URL' code you've got will work with this, just post the code and I'll help out.